# Deleting multiple key and value pairs from hash in Rails

Tags: ruby

```
number = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}
```

upon evaluation of certain condition i want to delete key-value pair of a,b,c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
number.delete "A"
number.delete "B"
number.delete "C"
```

Or, less performant but more terse:

```
number.reject! {|k, v| %w"A B C".include? k }
```

Comment: will the second approach be time consuming and effect performance

Comment: It creates new block and array objects, so it's slower and requires more RAM.

Answer (score 13):

or, more performant than second Chris' solution but shorter than first:

```
%w"A B C".each{|v| number.delete(v)}
```

Answer (score 11):

ActiveSupport that is a part of Rails comes with several built-in methods can help you to achieve your goal.

If you just want to delete some key-value pairs, you can use [Hash#except!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except-21)

```
number.except!(:a, :b, :c)
```

---

If you want to keep the original hash, then use [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except)

```
new_hash = number.except!(:a, :b, :c)

new_hash # => {:d=>4}
number # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

You also can go with Rails-free way:

```
new_hash = number.dup.tap do |hash|
  %i[a b c].each {|key| hash.delete(key)}
end

new_hash # => {:d=>4}
number # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

P.S.: the last code example is very slow, I'm just providing it as an alternative.